# Calling WordApplication.Open with VB6 fails when running as a service

Tags: com, vb6, ms-word

I am using this code to open a Word document:

```
Dim Word as Object, Doc as Object
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.application")
if not (Word is nothing) then
  set Doc = Word.Documents.Open("C:\temp\testfile.doc")
  if not (doc is nothing) then
    doc.close false
    set doc = nothing
  end if
  Word.Quit
  set Word = nothing
End if
```

I compiled it into an exe and it works fine when running it interactively or as a service on my test machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 with Office 2007). But on an other server with same OS and same Word version it works fine only when running the exe interactively. As soon as I run it as a service, the line

```
set Doc = Word.Documents.Open("C:\testfile.doc")
```

fails with the error "Object required".

I tried the following:

- Using the service account Local System
- Configured the service to use the same user account as I am logged on as
- Opening a new empty document with set Doc = Word.Documents.Add works fine
- I ran Word with the /r parameter to repair it and also with the /RegServer
- Checked / turned off Virus scanner (being MS Security Essentials)

No success.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You can sometimes cadge these things into working by first running a command prompt (or similar)(interactively) under the same account that the service runs under, and launching all of the applications that you need. But, at the end of the day, MS do not support automating Word from services, so you're on a path towards failure (even if you've not reached it today). You ought to look into server side solutions to generating the files you need to without trying to automate Word.

Comment: Hans, in the prodction code I am also checking on nothing of the Word object, so it is not that.

Comment: Dumping files into the root of the boot drive is also a consideration.  This not not an acceptable place for user data.

Comment: The example above is just an example - the actual files are not stored in the root but in a %temp% folder. I also tested it with files in the user's documents folder but it seems not to have anything to do with the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable your service to interact with the desktop. See screenshot in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237225/windows-service-allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop)