# prompt shell in window service via python

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, system, win32serviceutil

I want to prompt up a shell in windows service via python. The following is my code. It runs buy the prompt is running background instead of showing up. Thank you very much!

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event 
import requests
import sys
import subprocess
import os

class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "ServicePython"  # NET START/STOP the service by the following name
    _svc_display_name_ = "ServicePython Service"  # name in the Service  Control Manager (SCM)
    _svc_description_ = "This service writes stuff to a file"  #  description in the SCM

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager   
        self.start()  
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)  

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING) #tell the SCM 
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)         # fire the stop event
        self.stop()

    def start():
        pass  

    def stop():
        pass 

class MyService(PySvc): 
    def start(self):
        os.system("start cmd.exe /k \"cd /d C:\\ & dir\"") ####this does not show, runs at background only

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv.append("start")
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyService)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow service to interact with desktop in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237225/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop-in-windows)

Comment: The short answer appears to be that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Some how I solved the problem. Here are my steps:

1. install the windows service using the --interactive option.
   If the filename of the above python script is service.py, then install it via "python service.py --interactive install" in cmd. Start the service manually.
2. Use remote desktop to connect to session 0.
   Window services are displayed to only session 0's users by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/interactive-services). I follow the [link](https://www.veritas.com/content/support/en_US/article.100039314.html) to connect to session 0, and the prompt shell is now visible.

Thank you very much.