# Open JPG file fullscreen from .net service

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, service

I've developed a .net service and is up and running.
In the code I have to fetch some command and one of them could be to open an image fullscreen (or, in Windows 10, in presentation mode).

I already have my method and is working with other commands (like open notepad, or google chrome, etc)

```
Private Sub LaunchCommand(filename As String, arguments As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = filename
    startInfo.Arguments = arguments
    Process.Start(startInfo)
End Sub
```

What kind of arguments should i pass to that method?

With cmd I can only run

```
start "" /max "c:\path to my img\img.jpg"
```

**IMPORTANT:** I've already setted up permission and other OS stuff. I Just need to open the image.

Comment: Probably the service, that runs with a service account, must somehow [interact with the currently logged on user account and its Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4237225/107625).

Comment: @UweKeim as i write: I've already setted up permission and other OS stuff. Other commands are working

Comment: So it seems this is a question for Super User which can be reduced to "_How to show an image full screen from command line_", and has nothing to do with services at all.

Comment: Why not [launch Google Chrome in full screen](https://superuser.com/questions/430862/launch-google-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode), passing the image as the "URL"?

Comment: @UweKeim aready googled _"How to show an image full screen from command line"_ but nothing useful appears

Comment: @UweKeim while i was writing it i though about it. If im not going to find a different way I'll do it

Comment: The Widows viewers are applets, launched by rundll32.exe. For example, Windows 7 PhotoViewer can be started in full screen with `Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo startInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" startInfo.Arguments = $"{ChrW(34)}C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll{ChrW(34)}, ImageView_Fullscreen {fileName}" Process.Start(startInfo)`. Where `{fileName}` is the full path of the file to open. Better enclose it in quotation marks.