# RDPSession could not work in Windows Service app

Tags: c#, .net, remote-access, rdp, desktop-sharing

I have a desktop sharing WinForm application using RDPSession, it works well and client app can connect it via AxRDPViewer.

But after I change the sharing application type to Windows Service, the client app can only see a black screen of the sharer, like this
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHaes.jpg)

So I want to know if RDPSession can work in a Windows Service app ?
Any suggestions?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It cannot, because Services run in another [WindowsStation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-stations?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and thus cannot interact with the desktop directly

Comment: This [RDPSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/rdp/rdpsession)? The one that says `desktop apps | UWP apps` as the supported platforms?

Comment: Hi MindSwipe ,
thanks for your answer!
And I noticed in the service property, there is an option, 'permit to interact with desktop', what does this mean ?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237283/578411

Comment: OK, I see, thanks @rene