# Starting a windows application from a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I am trying to start a windows application from a windows Service using the below code

```
Process.Start(@"filename.exe");
```

In windows 7 I receive a popup that says, "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message"

Comment: you can use windows task scheduler please see [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c/51156657#51156657) .

Answer (score 5):

[You cannot start an interactive application from a Windows Service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/f8f91e8f-5954-43a7-8bc4-80ed2ff1e3b1/). This was changed in Windows Vista and 7.

Some other advice was given [in this Stack Overflow answer on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345620/alternative-to-allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop).

When I've needed to do this, I had to change my Windows Service to a Console Application, and invoked it in that manner.

Answer (score 3):

A work-around I found for this issue was to use the windows task scheduler. You can schedule the application to run some amount of seconds later by creating a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

At my previous company we had this issue and we wrote a console app that ran in the sys tray and acted as a bridge from the service to the desktop.  Basically via remoting (I'd use WCF now of course) we let the service request that the console app start up another application.