# Window services cant run exe on trigger time

Tags: service, window

I make one window service in c#
to run exe on particular time., but it could open that exe,
Below is code

```
    private static string   checkdatentime()
    {
        currentdate = DateTime.Now; 
        string value = "1";
        for (int i = 0; i < xml_date.Count; i++)
        {
            value = "2"; 
            if (currentdate.Date < xml_date[i].Date)
            {
                value = "3"; 
                break;
                // go out side for loop;

            }
            else if (currentdate.Date > xml_date[i].Date)
            {
                value = "4"; 
                //Do nothing means loops continues

            }
            else
            {
                value = "5"; 
                //if both date are same

                if (currentdate.Date == xml_date[i].Date)
                {
                    value = "99";
                    currentTime = currentdate.ToString("hh:mm");
                    TriggerTime = newItem.TriggerTime.ToString("hh:mm");

                    if (currentTime == TriggerTime)
                       {
                           value = "6"; 
                        //Run EXE
                           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\\SqlBackup_Programs\\console-backup\\Backup_Console_App 22July Latest\\Backup_Console_App\\Backup_Console_App\\bin\\Debug\\Backup_Console_App");
                        return value;
                     }

                }


            }


        }

        return value;
    }
```

NOTE: here I return value because to verify is my code runs correct or not and write VALUE on text file, so on same time I am getting VALUE=6, means there is no problem in code,
But still service cant open this exe,
by same code i made console application and its runs perfectly, so why not services??

Is this any problem with command,

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();

kindly help me!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c)

Comment: @James I am not satisfy with that conversation,
on that conversation they reach on conclusion tat its not possible in window services to run exe
But i think there should b a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I had checked the option "Allow to interact with the Desktop" in the Windows service properties
And now its Working