# visual c# - what is the easiest way to notify the current user from a windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, alert

I need to alert the current user from a windows service.
I have seen a few complicated methods on the internet, but most are dated.
I'm hoping something simple has come along for Windows 10.
One idea I am trying is creating a WPF application that has a simple message...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\blah\\WpfApplication1.exe");
```

... but it runs in background since the service doesn't know what user to run it for.
So I need to obtain the currently logged in desktop user (if there are multiple users then I'll notify all of them).  Then, if I could somehow use CreateProcessAsUser or something similar, that would do the trick.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I [pasted the meat of the subject line of your question into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+easiest+way+to+notify+the+current+user+from+a+windows+service) and found three helpful Stack Overflow posts in the top three hits. Good luck!

Comment: As I mentioned, I already did that.  Those articles are 5-6 years old.  And the ones referencing user notification are complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Services run in an elevated state called System that was designed by Microsoft to not interact with users. However there is a way to start an application from a service using this namespace that Microsoft wrote [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCreateProcessAsUserFromSe-b682134e).

Include the namespace in your code and execute it
`CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.LaunchChildProcess(PATH_TO_EXE)`

There is stackoverflow answer about this:

- [How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c)

Comment: the link to the one microsoft wrote looks promising.  I tried it and get oodles of errors that look like I'm missing a reference.  The link does not mention any required references, which happens all too frequently.  It looks like I might need a reference that has something to do with WTS and wtsapi32.dll but I can't find a matching reference.

Comment: Did you get error messages about trying to include it into your existing Windows Service? I had to compile it first, then add it to my existing Windows Service by selecting Project->Add Reference->Browse and then Browse to find the executable. Click OK and add `using CSCreateProcessAsUserFromService`

Comment: Where did you get or find the executable?  Are we talking about wtsapi32.dll?

Comment: @Xi Vix I was talking about the [CSCreateProcessAsUserFromService](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCreateProcessAsUserFromSe-b682134e) code. Once you download and compile that code, include it into your project and call `CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.LaunchChildProcess("C:\\blah\\WpfApplication1.exe")` to get your project up and running.

Comment: This worked!  I will add details as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

User Pixel answered my question but I wanted to provide more detail for future searchers.  The code is available at http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/FBB7577C/7A33AB93 but if it disappears just search for CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.  Paste the code into your Service1.cs workspace and remove the top namespace line and corresponding brackets since you already have a namespace.  So the first line will be:

```
class CreateProcessAsUserWrapper
```

Also, put it AFTER your service class, which must be the first class.  I did not have to add any using statements, so I don't know which ones it uses.  I'll paste all the ones I used below.

```
using Microsoft.Win32; // for registry key
using System;
using System.Collections; // for getfiles
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics; // for log writing
using System.IO; // for file watcher, file i/o, directory.exists
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // for SHGetKnownFolderPath
using System.Security.Permissions; // for file watcher, registry key
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading; // for sleep
using System.Timers; // for timers
```

Then, as Pixel mentioned, all you have to do is call it from inside your service like:

```
CreateProcessAsUserWrapper.LaunchChildProcess("C:\\blah\\WpfApplication1.exe")
```