# How to allow or permit Windows Service to open a exe/application

Tags: c#, com, activex

I have a windows service which tries to open a exe (COM component). The service is installed on Windows Server 2016. When the service tries to open the application, it is giving an error

> "Cannot create ActiveX component"

.  The opening of application is done by below line.

```
Interaction.CreateObject("Application.NewInstance")
```

I assume that service doesn't have permissions to open the application and that is why it is throwing an error. The same thing happened, when a web api is unable to open the application, it gave the same error. Then I gave permissions as below :

```
Go to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile" , give pull permissions to IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool user to AppData folder.
```

Since this is a Windows service, for what username (similar to IIS username) should I give permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp