# Service to run installers with administrative privileges

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, administration

I work at a company in which we need to restrict administrative access but allow the install of select programs with an easy way to update the list of programs. We want to develop a sort of appstore for everyone's PC where they can access the list of allowed apps and install what they need. We want to write this in C#.

To do this i have initially developed a windows service that starts as a localhost and runs at boot time giving it admin powers. I than use an application which talks to the windows service via a service hosted by the windows service. Long story short its told what app the user wants from the list and the list provides the file path for the application stored on a private repository.

This is a sort of very very early attempt at this and security is in mind and will be added once the concept functions.

Now onto the problem were having.... when we launch the installer using our service the installer window never launches in the desktop for the user to configure the options that could be in an installer. This of course poses a problem for a lot of our installers. After some quick research i understand why this happens due to what level the services run in the operating system and their inability to access the desktop.

My question is..... is there a way to solve this problem? a way to have a service launch at bootime and launch installers as an administrator on the users desktop? or is this too messy and creates too many issues? is there a way to do this with a console app or WPF?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed like what you found about windows services, I don't think this whole flow can work as a service. There seems to have some workarounds though, according to this thread: [How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c)

If it's an app-store where users can choose what to install, maybe an application is all that's needed. Like you said:

`I than use an application which talks to the windows service via a service hosted by the windows service. Long story short its told what app the user wants from the list and the list provides the file path for the application stored on a private repository.`

Seems like an application can handle all the works here already.

Comment: HI thanks for the reply. The only issue i found with the application is how do i get it to just run with administrator privileges upon startup with a normal domain user? Ive found they seem to prompt for admin credentials upon login..... i tried task scheduler but it doesn't behave as expected.