# Is it possible to open desktop app from Windows service

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a process monitoring service. This service should restart a Windows store app if it is not running.

Is it possible for Windows service to start desktop apps?

This works if I run it as a console app in C#

`Process.Start("C://myapp.exe");`

But when I use it in a service. Nothing happens.

Comment: Services start with a System Account that does not have any environmental variables.  So any application that uses the environment does not run correctly.  One way of solving issue is to create a service account.  Then start the service using Run As (requires an admin to setup) using the service account.

Comment: This may help you: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c)

Comment: @gacaba3982 Thank you for pointing out that post. One way I made it work is to change the service Log On to the account user. But this means I need to enter the username and password. Assuming there is only one user. Is there a way to do this programmatically?