# Send Windows Toast to logged on user from system account

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a simple console application in c# that will send the logged-on user a toast message. The application will be called from a windows service that is running under the system account.

How can I run the application as the system account and display the toast message to the logged-on user?

Using Visual Studio 2022 I published the project as a single exe and copied it to another Windows 11 workstation. The application runs as expected when running from the user's command prompt or setting the service to run as that user.

When running as the system user the applications launches however the toast is never displayed.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
using System.IO;

new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
    .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
    .AddText("Security Notification")
    .AddText("A Honeypot file has been modified!")
    .Show();
;
```

Comment: Windows services run under session 0 (non-interactive), and you are trying to call an exe an run it on an interactive session. This is not a normal thing to do for security reasons. You should research IPC (Inter-process communication). Maybe start with Named Pipes.

Comment: good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c)

Comment: Now also that there can be more than one logged on user (or no logged on user at all).