# Not able to open file explorer ,on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, node.js

my code in node js side is-

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

        var cmdString = 'start C:/myApp/dropbox';

        const child = exec(cmdString,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {

            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
        })
```

if i start the application from command prompt, I am able to open windows file explore on clicking a button.

But, if i start the application from windows service. I am not able to open file explorer.

Any idea what mistake i am doing in my coding side.

Comment: What is it your actually trying to do, as open windows explorer for a windows service doesn't make any sense.  In the windows server there is an interact with Desktop option, but I'd say doing this is just not really a good idea.  In a multi-user system, aka TSE, it's only going to open in the main console.

Comment: i created service for my node app. if i start with my created service. I am not able to open file explorer on a button click.

Comment: I checked that option too, it did not work.

Comment: Presenting UI from a windows service is very atypical and not recommended. Check this out for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347464/running-ui-with-windows-service